# How to specify parenthesis in QueryDSL?

Tags: querydsl

Borrowing an example from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression:

```
WITH RECURSIVE temp (n, fact) AS 
(SELECT 0, 1 -- Initial Subquery
  UNION ALL 
 SELECT n+1, (n+1)*fact FROM temp -- Recursive Subquery 
        WHERE n < 9)
SELECT * FROM temp;
```

How would you express `(n+1)*fact` versus `n+(1*fact)` in the SELECT clause using QueryDSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querydsl handles parenthesis internally in the serialization. Your expressions can be expressed like this in Querydsl

```
n.add(1).times(fact)
```

and

```
n.add(fact.times(1))
```